# How to read excel data in selenium using Map

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng-dataprovider

I have excel file having the below data, and i am trying to fetch the data through data provider method.
The scenario here is - if the value of "To Be Executed" is "Yes" then that respective testcase scenario needs to be run.

But i am facing problem here. Find the snippet of excel file and code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
public Boolean getDataFromExcel(String excelName, String sheetName) {
        wb = getExcelWorkbook(excelName);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        //Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);
         Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                //For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {        

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    if(cell.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                            return true;
                            
                    }
                    else
                    return false;
```